# How to remove default mapping of index without deleting its data of elasticsearch

Tags: c#-4.0, elasticsearch, couchbase, nest

I have some documents in Couch-base in which some field values are having space in it ("Ex. "New York").
I am not able to search it as exact match using term query.
I found that for searching the field values which are have space require some mapping like - `index : not_analysed`

and I have done the same

But when I am doing XDCR from couch base to elastic search .Couch base itself creates default mapping.Because of which I am not getting proper result.

So, is there any way by which we can delete default mapping without deleting its data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please refer the below code.**
I have created and mapped index with dynamic template and then did the XDCR. 
Now all string fields will be not_analysed.

```
 IIndicesOperationResponse result = null;
                    if (!objElasticClient.IndexExists(elastic_indexname).Exists)
                    {
                        result = objElasticClient.CreateIndex(elastic_indexname, c => c.AddMapping<dynamic>(m => m.Type("_default_").DynamicTemplates(t => t
                                                    .Add(f => f.Name("string_fields").Match("*").MatchMappingType("string").Mapping(ma => ma
                                                        .String(s => s.Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)))))));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can change the mappings (check out the mappings API) but in practice I've found it more or less impossible because of conflicts with the existing mappings.

So:

1) Create mappings before indexing any data
2) Apply some of the ideas from this blog post: https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution
 Here I have created and mapped index with dynamic template and then did the XDCR. Now all string fields will be not_analysed.It worked for me.

```
IIndicesOperationResponse result = null;
                    if (!objElasticClient.IndexExists(elastic_indexname).Exists)
                    {
                        result = objElasticClient.CreateIndex(elastic_indexname, c => c.AddMapping<dynamic>(m => m.Type("_default_").DynamicTemplates(t => t
                                                    .Add(f => f.Name("string_fields").Match("*").MatchMappingType("string").Mapping(ma => ma
                                                        .String(s => s.Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)))))));
                }
```

Thanks

Mukesh Raghuwanshi